# googlebot reading site in incorrect language

Tags: mediawiki, user-agent, googlebot

My site was hacked and the useragent is sending googlebot the incorrect page. It looks like it is reading it the wrong language as a result of the extra code:

```
dir="ltr" lang="ja" xml:lang="ja"> <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

I can't find where the code is in the files. It is a mediawiki site. 
How do I fix this?

Comment: You should delete the entire MediaWiki directory (keep `LocalSettings.php`) and copy the latest MediaWiki release in its place instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hack was in the index.php file. 
I removed the code that was including a page created by the hackers.